# Scrollable tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs

I am trying to have scrollable tabs in android. I tried to apply a `HorizontalScrollView` to the `TabWidget`, but it didn't work.
Any ideas why it does not work?

Here is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none">
      <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it is working for me:-**

```
 <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
      </LinearLayout>
      </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier. I was doing the same thing, but putting Tabwidget in HorizontalScrollView is not enough, it shrinks during runtime. So we have to define the height and width of widget during runtime through the loop. Like the below

```
for(int i=0;i<=numbeOfTabs;i++)
        {
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width=100;
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height=100;
        }
```